# Rest List Filter Query Multi Line search

Tags: office-365, rest

I have created a form and am using bootstrap, jquery and knockout to display the results nicely from a discussion board in office 365.

I am querying a list using the rest api and applying a filter to a multi line text field which is where the user enters the description of the discussion.

However I keep getting the exception "The field 'body' of type 'Note' cannot be used in the query filter expression when using rest.

How do I get round this issue. I have customised the discussion forum so don't want to use out the box look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

To search e.g. Note -type of fields with REST you should use the [Search REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx).

To return the search as JSON you'd pass the header as `'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'`